# Some element rendered twice in nuxt3

Tags: nuxt3

This is the Vue component:

```
<template #header>
  <div class="flex items-center text-center home-floor">
    <div class="home-floor__back"></div>
    <div class="flex-1">
      <van-popover
        v-model:show="showPopover"
        :show-arrow="false"
        class="popover-floor"
      >
        <template #reference>
          <div class="home-floor__header">
            <span class="home-floor__header--text ellipsis">
              {{ activeFloor?.floorName }}
            </span>
            <svg-icon
              v-if="floorList?.length"
              :class="`inline-block align-baseline home-floor__header--icon ml-1 ${
                showPopover ? 'floor-icon-up' : 'floor-icon-down'
              }`"
              name="arrowdown"
            />
          </div>
        </template>
        <ul class="home-floor__ul floorlist">
          <li
            v-for="item in floorList"
            :key="item.floorId"
            class="flex items-center justify-between floorlist-item"
            @click="selectFloor(item)"
          >
            <div>{{ item.floorName }}</div>
            <van-icon
              v-if="item.floorId === activeFloorId"
              class="pl-4"
              color="#147fff"
              name="success"
            />
          </li>
        </ul>
      </van-popover>
    </div>
    <svg-icon
      v-if="hasLogin"
      class="home-floor__share"
      name="share"
      @click="hanlderShare"
    />
    <div class="home-floor__avatar">
      <clientOnly>
        <van-popover
          v-if="hasLogin"
          v-model:show="showAvatarPopover"
          :show-arrow="false"
          placement="bottom-end"
          class="popover-avatar"
        >
          <template #reference>
            <img
              :src="userInfo.avatarUrl"
              class="avatar"
              round
              @error="hanlderDefaultImage"
              @click="handlerToLogin"
            />
          </template>
          <ul class="home-avatar__ul avatarlist">
            <li
              v-for="item in avatarActions"
              :key="item.text"
              class="flex items-center justify-between avatarlist-item"
              @click="handlerAvatarPopover(item.text)"
            >
              <div class="w-full ellipsis">{{ item.text }}</div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </van-popover>
        <img
          v-else
          :src="UnLogoImageUrl"
          class="avatar"
          round
          @click="handlerToLogin"
        />
      </clientOnly>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="home-spu">
    <van-tabs
      v-model:active="activeSpuId"
      :swipe-threshold="1"
      :key="activeFloorId"
      ref="spuTabsVm"
      animated
      swipeable
      @change="clickSpuTab"
    >
      <van-tab
        v-for="spuItem in activeFloor?.homeFloorSpuList || []"
        :key="spuItem.spuId"
        :name="spuItem.spuId"
        title-class="home-spu__item"
      >
        <template #title>
          <a class="home-spu__item--title" href="javascript: void(0);">
            {{ spuItem.spuName }}
          </a>
        </template>
      </van-tab>
    </van-tabs>
  </div>
</template>
```

When I browse in the browser[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIwC2.jpg)
It looks normal

When I browse in the webview of the app, It has been rendered twice

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1YUQ.jpg)

I try to use span like this:

```
<template #header>
  <span class="flex items-center text-center home-floor">
    <span class="home-floor__back"></span>
    <span class="flex-1">
      <van-popover
        v-model:show="showPopover"
        :show-arrow="false"
        class="popover-floor"
      >
        <template #reference>
          <span class="home-floor__header">
            <span class="home-floor__header--text ellipsis">
              {{ activeFloor?.floorName }}
            </span>
            <svg-icon
              v-if="floorList?.length"
              :class="`inline-block align-baseline home-floor__header--icon ml-1 ${
                showPopover ? 'floor-icon-up' : 'floor-icon-down'
              }`"
              name="arrowdown"
            />
          </span>
        </template>
        <ul class="home-floor__ul floorlist">
          <li
            v-for="item in floorList"
            :key="item.floorId"
            class="flex items-center justify-between floorlist-item"
            @click="selectFloor(item)"
          >
            <span>{{ item.floorName }}</span>
            <van-icon
              v-if="item.floorId === activeFloorId"
              class="pl-4"
              color="#147fff"
              name="success"
            />
          </li>
        </ul>
      </van-popover>
    </span>
    <svg-icon
      v-if="hasLogin"
      class="home-floor__share"
      name="share"
      @click="hanlderShare"
    />
    <span class="home-floor__avatar">
      <clientOnly>
        <van-popover
          v-if="hasLogin"
          v-model:show="showAvatarPopover"
          :show-arrow="false"
          placement="bottom-end"
          class="popover-avatar"
        >
          <template #reference>
            <img
              :src="userInfo.avatarUrl"
              class="avatar"
              round
              @error="hanlderDefaultImage"
              @click="handlerToLogin"
            />
          </template>
          <ul class="home-avatar__ul avatarlist">
            <li
              v-for="item in avatarActions"
              :key="item.text"
              class="flex items-center justify-between avatarlist-item"
              @click="handlerAvatarPopover(item.text)"
            >
              <span class="w-full ellipsis"> {{ item.text }} </span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </van-popover>
        <img
          v-else
          :src="UnLogoImageUrl"
          class="avatar"
          round
          @click="handlerToLogin"
        />
      </clientOnly>
    </span>
  </span>
</template>
```

When I browse in the webview of the app, it looks normal.But when I click some element, elements will not be updated, and error reporting
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYLyO.jpg)